# Arithmetic operations on y(x) functions in R

Tags: r, operator-overloading, arithmetic-expressions

Suppose we have data frame `f` with two columns `x` and `y` where all values in `f$x` go in ascending order. We can treat it as a function y(x).

I want to perform arithmetic operations on such data frames like on functions in mathematical sense. For example:

```
# f1 stores points of y1(x)
# f2 stores points of y2(x)
f3 <- 2*f1 + 3*f2
# now f3 stores points of y3(x) = 2*y1(x) + 3*y2(x)
```

There is no problem if `x` arrays are the same for all functions, but in my case they can represent **different ranges with different density of the points**.

So I need to work in the interval where both functions are defined and make interpolation (linear is enough) to get the values of the functions between known points.

Are there any packages where it is already implemented?

Comment: Have a look at the help for `findInterval` and `approx` - these might be of use in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The zoo library has a simple spline extrapollation function, which could be useful. This would allow to have similar ranges.

```
library(zoo)
my.df <-matrix(c(1:5,NA),ncol=2,nrow=15)
na.spline(my.df)

          [,1]     [,2]
 [1,] 1.000000 4.000000
 [2,] 2.000000 5.000000
 [3,] 3.000000 2.767553
 [4,] 4.000000 1.000000
 [5,] 5.000000 2.000000
 [6,] 3.002711 3.000000
 [7,] 1.000000 4.000000
 [8,] 2.000000 5.000000
 [9,] 3.000000 2.997556
[10,] 4.000000 1.000000
[11,] 5.000000 2.000000
[12,] 3.017224 3.000000
[13,] 1.000000 4.000000
[14,] 2.000000 5.000000
[15,] 3.000000 5.932149
```